# Как узнать, какая ES версия JS у меня установлена?

Tags: javascript

Как узнать, какая ES версия JS у меня установлена?

Answer (score 1):

Всю подробную информацию о поддержки браузерами стандарта можно посмотреть на сайте https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/  Она очень подробная. Не только какая общая версия, но и точечные поддержки. Например strings trimming

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сверху есть фильтр по версиям ES

Пример таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Более общая информация тут https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_versions.asp

Comment: Я не об этом спрашивал. Мне на собеседовании задали вопрос: какую версию JS вы используете? ES5, или может быть ES6? Ввиду того, что ничего не знал про ES, я не смог ответить на этот вопрос. Поэтому и спрашиваю, как это определить?

Comment: Алексей неверно понял ваш вопрос, да. Но и вы неверно понимаете вопрос из собеседования. Вас спросили: на какой версии js _вы_ пишите. Т.е. «какая версия js у вас в голове». Браузер тут совершенно не при чём - _в вашей голове_

Comment: @ОлегВерушкин см выше ↑   ES - это стандарт, по которому пишется код.  Версию какого стандарта вы используете - знаете только вы сами и пишите код согласно этим стандартам, которые поддерживают соответствтвующие браузеры

Comment: @ОлегВерушкин https://tproger.ru/translations/wtf-is-ecmascript/

Comment: и тут, оказывается, что табличка Алексея может пригодиться! двигайтесь по ней снизу вверх и в каждой строке отвечайте на два вопроса «знаю ли я это?» и «использую ли я это?». там, где наберётся что-то значимое и будет вашей версией. а если не наберется - ищите предыдущие спецификации